# How can I cache Sonar plugins in Azure DevOps Pipelines so that they don't download everytime the pipeline runs?

Tags: caching, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I use the Sonar tasks in my Azure DevOps pipeline to run static analysis on my code, but I would like to avoid having the pipeline download the plugins everytime the pipeline runs.

I think I could use the Cache task but I'm not sure how should I configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. My pipeline was downloading the Sonar plugins every time and taking about `40~60 seconds`.

I was able to cache the plugins through the `.sonar/cache` folder and decrease the download time to around `8~12 seconds`.

Example:

```yaml
variables:
  SONAR_PLUGINS: /home/vsts/.sonar/cache

steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: sonar | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.Repository.Name)
      path: $(SONAR_PLUGINS)
    displayName: cache sonar plugins
```

Comment: is the repo name required?  i thought the cache task was already isolated tot he current pipeline

Comment: You are right, I think it can be removed.